# Typescript (2.7+) > Multiple types for a parameter > Handle specific properties

Tags: typescript

Consider a **ChildClass** extending the **ParentClass**. Stackblitz available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mrrsdy) for this question.

**ChildClass** only adds a public property ("brainPower") :

```
class ParentClass{

  _me: string;

  constructor() {
    this._me = "I'm a parent";
  }

  whoAmI(): string {
    return this._me;
  }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

  public readonly brainPower = 42;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._me = "I'm a child";
  }
}
```

A method "**doStuff**" takes one parameter of either kinds:

```
class Program {

  static main() {
    Program.doStuff(new ParentClass());
    Program.doStuff(new ChildClass());
  }

  static doStuff(anInstance: ParentClass | ChildClass){

    console.log('[Program] > Processing > ', anInstance.whoAmI());

    if(anInstance.brainPower){
      console.log('[Processing] > ', anInstance.whoAmI(), ' > I can brain as much as ', anInstance.brainPower);
    }
  }
}
```

**My problem**

The Typescript compiler reports:

```
Property 'brainPower' does not exist on type 'ParentClass | ChildClass'.
```

**Question** is how to set multiple possible types for a parameter and expect typescript to understand it so that a property only known to one of the types is accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the parameter of the function to accept any instance of `ParentClass`.

Instead of checking if the property exists, you could check if the given object is an instance of `ChildClass`

```
if (anInstance instanceof ChildClass) ...
```

The ts compiler will infer the object as an instance of ChildClass within the if scope.